# React Native Router Flux: passing params between scenes

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a list of items (jobs) and when an item (job) is being selected, a new scene is being opened. I want the ID of the selected item to be passed from the scene with the list to the other scene with the details about the selected item (job) without using Redux.

Router

```
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import JobsList from './components/JobsList';
import Job from './components/Job';

const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="jobs" component={JobsList} initial />
      <Scene key="Job" component={Job} title="Test" />
    </Router>
  );
};
export default RouterComponent;
```

Jobs list

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class JobsList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { Actions.Job({ jobId: jobId }) }}>
      ...
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Job

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Job extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      job: {}
    };

    axios.get(
      // PROBLEM: this.props.jobId is empty
      `http://api.tidyme.dev:5000/${this.props.jobId}.json`,
      {
        headers: { Authorization: 'Token token=123' }
      }
    ).then(response => this.setState({
      job: response.data
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{this.state.job.customer.firstName}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `super(props)` if you want to access `this.props` inside the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log(this.props);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this best practice or should I rather set up Redux to handle this?

Comment: If the prop is used by many scenes then redux is better. Otherwise the above should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is defining Components as pure functions:

```
const Job = ({ job, JobId}) => {
return (
   <Text>{job.customer.firstName}</Text>
  );
}

otherFunctions() {
  ...
}
```